# How to access the WebResponse in a WCF Data Service client so that I can use the cookies it contains?

Tags: .net, authentication, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm writing a .NET app that calls a WCF Data Service that requires authentication credentials to be passed in an HTTP header. I'm setting that header in a DataServiceContext.SendingRequest event handler. The service then returns an authentication token in a cookie. The client is expected to provide this cookie on subsequent calls. I can set cookies in the SendingRequest event, but I've been unable to find a way to hook the response in order to get the cookie in the first place. (Why isn't there a DataServiceContext.ResponseReceived event?) Can anyone tell me either (1) how to hook the response so that I can read the HttpWebResponse.Cookies collection, or (2) how to configure the WCF Data Service client plumbing to handle cookies automatically?

Thanks for any insights or direction!

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this through event handlers. But you can get to it through the OperationResponse. For example if you invoke the query by running Execute it returns an instance which derives from OperationResponse (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.operationresponse.aspx). That exposes the response headers. This is also true for SaveChanges and so on.

Comment: Thanks, Vitek. This works. It seems somewhat brittle, since DataServiceQuery.Execute isn't documented to return an OperationResponse, but I think it's the best option that doesn't require changing server-side code. I really appreciate this answer.

Comment: I consider that a bug in the documentation, it is totally supported and guaranteed to return OperationResponse (in fact Execute will return QueryOperationResponse<T>).

Comment: That's really good to know! Even better than documentation would be if this were baked into the contract. The static return type of Execute is IEnumerable<T>. If we're meant to rely on the runtime type being derived from OperationResponse, then ideally Execute's return type would be something like OperationResponse<T> (which I realize doesn't exist), which in turn would be defined to implement IEnumerable<T>. Thanks again for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for, and I wasn't expecting to find it.

Comment: The actual return type is QueryOperationResponse<T> which does derive from IEnumerable<T>. I honestly don't know why the method is declared to return IEnumerable<T>. Unfortunately I'm not sure it's possible to fix this, it might be a breaking change.

Comment: It might not be a breaking change. Existing clients rely on the return type being IEnumerable<T>. Since QueryOperationResponse<T> implements IEnumerable<T>, current clients shouldn't be bothered if the return type is changed to QueryOperationResponse<T>. But I don't know enough to know if such a change would require a recompile of the consumer.

Comment: But maybe a better change would be to add a DataServiceContext.ResponseReceived event, and have the event args contain the OperationResponse. This would fit better with the existing design.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear where you need to access the cookie value, but you should be able to hook into the processing pipeline by wiring up an event handler in your service's constructor, e.g:

```
public ScratchService()
{
    ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += (source, e) =>
        {
            WebHeaderCollection headers = e.OperationContext.RequestHeaders;
            string acceptHeader = headers["CustomCookie"];
            if (acceptHeader == null || !acceptHeader.Equals("Passw0rd"))
            {
                throw new DataServiceException(403, "You had a bad cookie.");
            }
        };
}
```

ProcessingRequest happens before the rest of the pipeline is invoked, so that should be a reasonable place for you to put your authentication in. Obviously you'll want something slightly more secure than the example above. :)

Comment: Mark, thanks for your reply. However, my need is client-side. I need access to the WebResponse received on the client after the DataServiceContext has issued its WebRequest. Something comparable to DataServiceContext.SendingRequest, but for the response rather than the request.